# Rerendering d3 graph in react

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, graphql, next.js, apollo-client

I'm working on generating a d3 polar graph that holds musical data and am working on filtering search by name. I have a text input and submit button in its own component and just want to filter my object by artist name right now.

I've tried two methods. One using apollo client cache and updating the cache on submit (which im not sure I'm implementing correctly) The other method was writing an event listener in d3 object to run a function filter and rerender the graph. I did something similar to rerender  by using a checkbox to trigger the initvis function to filter my data by by key signature and rerender the graph on the page (which works). 0 is minor 1 is major. As of right now the graph isnt able to rerender. the data in graph.js doesnt seem to mutate with apollo, and the way im trying to filter isn't giving me any results either. Thanks!

searchbar.js

```
import styles from './searchbar.module.css';

import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';
import axios from 'axios';

import { songsVar } from '../lib/apolloClient'
import { setInfo } from '../redux/actions/main.js'
import { tracksVar } from '../pages/index'

const myQuery = gql`
query getsongs ($artist: String) {
  songs (filter: { artists: {contains: $artist }}) {
    name
    artists
    key
    mode
    tempo
    releaseYear
  }
}
`


export default function Searchbar({ placeholder, initialApolloState }) {
  // const songs = songsVar()
  // console.log('initialApolloState in searchBar', initialApolloState())
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('')
  const { loading, error, data, refetch, client } = useQuery(myQuery, {
    variables: {artist: searchQuery}
  });
  // if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error :</p>;
    
    const onChange = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setSearchQuery(e.target.value);
      console.log('songsvar on form change -->', songsVar())
    }
    
    const handleClick = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      songsVar(searchQuery)
      tracksVar(searchQuery)
      console.log('data in SearchBar -->', data)
      console.log('songsvar data in SearchBar -->', songsVar())
      console.log('tracksVar data in SearchBar -->', tracksVar())
    
    }

  //GraphQL query
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="field has-addons">
        <div className="control">
          <input
            className="input"
            data-testid="searchInput"
            type="text"
            id="qInput"
            placeholder={placeholder}
            onChange={onChange}
            value={searchQuery} 
          />
        </div>
        <div className="control ">
          <button className="button" id="aeriaSearchButton" onClick={handleClick}>
            {/* <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSearch} /> */}S
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

graph.js (react component)

```
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';

import axios from 'axios'
import styles from './graph.module.css';
import D3Component from '../lib/d3display';
import { songsVar } from '../lib/apolloClient'
import { tracksVar } from '../pages/index.js'

let vis;


export default function Graph({initialApolloState}) {
    
    const songsQuery = gql`
    query allSongs{
        songs {
            name
            artists
            key
            mode
            tempo
            releaseYear
        }
    }`

    const { data } = useQuery(songsQuery);
    const currSongsVar = songsVar(data)
    const currSongsVar2 = tracksVar()

    // const [graphData, setGraphData] = useState(currSongsVar2);
    
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(600);
    const [height, setHeight] = useState(600);
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
    const [keySig, setKeySig] = useState('Minor');
    const [bgColor, setBgColor] = useState('#360071');
    const [textColor, setTextColor] = useState('beige');
    const [lineColor, setLineColor] = useState('beige');
    const [artist, setArtist] = useState('');
    const [zoomState, setCurrentZoomState] = useState();
    
    const refElement = useRef(null);
    
    useEffect(handleResizeEvent, []);
    useEffect(initVis, [songsVar(), artist, active]);
    useEffect(updateVisOnResize, [width, height]);
    
    function majorOrMinor() {
      if (active === false) {
          setBgColor('beige') 
          setActive(true)
          setKeySig('Major')
          setTextColor('black')
          setLineColor('beige')
        }
      else {
          setBgColor('#360071') ;
          setActive(false);
          setKeySig('Minor');
          setTextColor('beige')
          setLineColor('#360071')
        } 
    }

    function handleResizeEvent() {
        let resizeTimer;
        const handleResize = () => {
            clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
            resizeTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                setWidth(width);
                setHeight(height);
            }, 300);
        };
        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        };
    }

    function initVis() {
        setArtist(tracksVar())
        if (currSongsVar && currSongsVar.songs.length) {
            songsVar(songsVar())
            const d3Props = {
                data: currSongsVar.songs,
                width,
                height,
                textColor,
                backgroundColor: bgColor,
                lineColor,
                artist: currSongsVar2,
                onDatapointClick: setActive
            };
            vis = new D3Component(refElement.current, d3Props);
            
        }
        else console.log('no data')
    }

    function updateVisOnResize() {
        vis && vis.resize(width, height);
    }

    return (
        <div className='react-world'>
            {/* <div>{keySig}</div> */}
            <input type="checkbox" className={styles.checkBox} id="checkBox" name="major/minor" value="major/minor" checked={active} onChange={majorOrMinor}></input>
            <div id="d3Graph" key={new Date().getTime()} ref={refElement} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

d3graph.js

````
import { useState } from 'react';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import { entries, text, zoomTransform } from 'd3';

export default class D3Display {
  containerEl;
  props;
  svg;

  constructor(containerEl, props) {
    this.containerEl = containerEl;
    this.props = props;
    const { width, height, backgroundColor} = props;

    
    this.svg = d3
    .select(containerEl)
    .append('svg')
    .style('background-color', backgroundColor)
    .attr('id', 'd3Canvas')
    .attr('width', width + 20 + 20)
    .attr('height', height + 20 + 20)
    .attr('class', 'radar' + containerEl);
    this.updateDatapoints();
  }
  

  updateDatapoints = () => {
    //deconstructs variable
    const {
      svg,
      props: { data, width, height, textColor, lineColor, artist},
    } = this;
    const keysToString = {
      8: 'c',
      3: 'c#',
      10: 'd',
      5: 'd#',
      0: 'e',
      7: 'f',
      2: 'f#',
      9: 'g',
      4: 'g#',
      11: 'a',
      6: 'a#',
      1: 'b',
    };

    const apiNotesToWheelNotes = {
      0: 8,
      1: 3,
      2: 10,
      3: 5,
      4: 0,
      5: 7,
      6: 2,
      7: 9,
      8: 4,
      9: 11,
      10: 6,
      11: 1,
    };
    let transform;
    const zoomBehavior = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1,5])
      .translateExtent([[0,0],[width, height]])
      .on('zoom', () => {
        console.log('zoomed')
        const zoomState = zoomTransform(svg.node())
        //set current zoom state
        console.log('zoomState -->', zoomState)
        transform = d3.event.transform;
        console.log('transform', transform);
        // svg.attr('transform', transform.toString());
        
      });
    svg.call(zoomBehavior);
    //EVENT HANDLER FOR CHECKBOX
    d3.select("#checkBox").on('change', modeChange) 
    //EVENT HANDLER FOR Searchbar
    d3.select('#aeriaSearchButton').on('click', filterGraph)


    let radius = 200;
    let maxValue = 200;
    // let maxValue = Math.max(0, d3.max(data, (i) => d3.max(i.map(o => o.value))))
    // All songs/rows by key
    let allAxis = data.map((i, j) => i['key']);
    const removeDuplicates = (inputArr) => {
      let uniqueVals = {};
      return inputArr.filter((el) => {
        return uniqueVals.hasOwnProperty(el) ? false : (uniqueVals[el] = true);
      });
    };
    //select tempos
    let allTempos = data.map((i, j) => i['tempo']);

    // numRange creates 0-11 range of notes from data
    let numRange = Object.keys(removeDuplicates(allAxis));
    let total = numRange.length;
    // let radius = Math.min(width / 2, height / 2)
    let angleSlice = (Math.PI * 2) / total;
    //scale for radius and tempo
    let rScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, radius]).domain([0, maxValue]);

    //mode range will always be constant
    // g creates the area to draw on
    let g = svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', `translate(${width / 2},${height / 2})`)
      // .attr('transform', "translate(" + transform + ")" + " scale(" + transform + ")");
    

    //circular grid
    let axisGrid = g.append('g').attr('class', 'axisWrapper');
    axisGrid
      .selectAll('.levels')
      .data(d3.range(1, 5).reverse())
      .join('circle')
      .attr('class', 'gridCircle')
      .attr('r', (d, i) => (radius / 4) * d)
      .style('fill', '#CDCDCD')
      .style('stroke', '#CDCDCD')
      .style('fill-opacity', 0.1);

    //text indicating bpm
    axisGrid
      .selectAll('.axisLabel')
      .data(d3.range(1, 5))
      .join('text')
      .attr('class', 'axisLabel')
      .attr('x', (d) => (d * radius) / 4)
      .attr('y', 4 * Math.sin(angleSlice / 20 - Math.PI / 2))
      .attr('dy', '0.1em')
      .style('font-size', '10px')
      .attr('fill', '#737373')
      .text((d, i) => {
        return (200 * d) / 4 + 'bpm';
      });

    //create key line points from center
    //REMOVE DUPLICATES from DATA pull filter range to be 1[7]
    let axis = axisGrid
      .selectAll('.axis')
      .data(numRange) // [0-11]
      .join('g')
      .attr('class', 'axis');
    // //append the lines
    axis
      .append('line')
      .attr('x1', 0)
      .attr('y1', 0)
      .attr(
        'x2',
        (d, i) =>
          rScale(maxValue * 1.1) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2)
      )
      .attr(
        'y2',
        (d, i) =>
          rScale(maxValue * 1.1) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2)
      )
      .attr('class', 'line')
      .attr('stroke', lineColor)
      .attr('stroke-width', '2px');
    //create key names on each line
    axis
      .append('text')
      .attr('class', 'legend')
      .style('font-size', '11px')
      .style('fill', textColor)
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .attr('dy', '0.35em')
      .attr(
        'x',
        (d, i) =>
          rScale(maxValue * 1.25) * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2)
      )
      .attr(
        'y',
        (d, i) =>
          rScale(maxValue * 1.25) * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2)
      )
      .text((d) => {
        return keysToString[d];
      })
      .call(wrap, 60);

    // need tempo range 0-200 x
    // need song key to be [0-11]
    // songPositions are the dots on the board
    let songPositions;
    let newData;
   
    function modeChange(){
      let circleColor;
      let textColor;
      //if statements changes mode from minor 0 to major 1
      if (d3.select("#checkBox").property("checked")) {
        newData = data.filter((el, i) => i <= 20 && el.mode === 1)
        circleColor ='#360071'
        textColor = 'black'
      }
      else {
        newData = data.filter((el, i) => i <= 20 && el.mode === 0)
        circleColor = 'beige'
        textColor = 'white'
      };

      songPositions = g
      .selectAll('.songPositions')
      .data(newData, (d) => d) // currently selecting less than 20 songs in DB and only songs in Major Keys
      .join('g')
      .attr('class', '.songPositions');
      
      songPositions
        .append('circle')
        .attr('class', 'radarCircle')
        .attr('r', 4)
        .attr('cx', function (d, i) {
          return (
            rScale(d.tempo) *
            Math.cos(angleSlice * apiNotesToWheelNotes[d.key] - Math.PI / 2)
          );
        })
        .attr('cy', function (d, i) {
          return (
            rScale(d.tempo) *
            Math.sin(angleSlice * apiNotesToWheelNotes[d.key] - Math.PI / 2)
          );
        })
        .style('fill', circleColor)
        .style('fill-opacity', 0.8)

        
      //append text label to dots
      songPositions
        .append('text')
        .attr('class', 'songName')
        .style('font-size', '8px')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'right')
        .style('fill', textColor)
        .attr('dy', '1em')
        .attr('dx', '1em')
        .attr('x', function (d, i) {
          return (
            rScale(d.tempo) *
            Math.cos(angleSlice * apiNotesToWheelNotes[d.key] - Math.PI / 2)
          );
        })
        .attr('y', function (d, i) {
          return (
            rScale(d.tempo) *
            Math.sin(angleSlice * apiNotesToWheelNotes[d.key] - Math.PI / 2)
          );
        })
        .text((d) => `${d.name} - ${d.artists}`)
        .call(wrap, 60);
    }
    modeChange()

    function filterGraph(){
      //artist is the variable from gql search
      
      // let songPositions;
      // let newData;
      let circleColor;
      let textColor;
      //if statements changes mode from minor 0 to major 1
      if (d3.select("#checkBox").property("checked")) {
        //add artist category/variable
        newData = data.filter((el) => el.artists == artist)
        circleColor ='#360071'
        textColor = 'black'
      }
      else {
        //add artist category/variable
        newData = data.filter((el) => {
          return el.artists == artist;
        })
        console.log('newData false',data.filter((el) => {
          return el.artists == artist;
        }))
        circleColor = 'beige'
        textColor = 'white'
      };
  
      
  
      songPositions = g
      .selectAll('.songPositions')
      .data(newData, (d) => d) // currently selecting less than 20 songs in DB and only songs in Major Keys
      .join('g')
      .attr('class', '.songPositions');
      
      songPositions
        .append('circle')
        .attr('class', 'radarCircle')
        .attr('r', 4)
        .attr('cx', function (d, i) {
          return (
            rScale(d.tempo) *
            Math.cos(angleSlice * apiNotesToWheelNotes[d.key] - Math.PI / 2)
          );
        })
        .attr('cy', function (d, i) {
          return (
            rScale(d.tempo) *
            Math.sin(angleSlice * apiNotesToWheelNotes[d.key] - Math.PI / 2)
          );
        })
        .style('fill', circleColor)
        .style('fill-opacity', 0.8)
  
        
      //append text label to dots
      songPositions
        .append('text')
        .attr('class', 'songName')
        .style('font-size', '8px')
        .attr('text-anchor', 'right')
        .style('fill', textColor)
        .attr('dy', '1em')
        .attr('dx', '1em')
        .attr('x', function (d, i) {
          return (
            rScale(d.tempo) *
            Math.cos(angleSlice * apiNotesToWheelNotes[d.key] - Math.PI / 2)
          );
        })
        .attr('y', function (d, i) {
          return (
            rScale(d.tempo) *
            Math.sin(angleSlice * apiNotesToWheelNotes[d.key] - Math.PI / 2)
          );
        })
        .text((d) => `${d.name} - ${d.artists}`)
        .call(wrap, 60);
    }
    
  };

  



  setActiveDatapoint = (d, node) => {
    d3.select(node).style('fill', 'yellow');
    this.props.onDatapointClick(d);
  };

  resize = (width, height) => {
    const { svg } = this;
    svg.attr('width', width).attr('height', height);
    svg
      .selectAll('circle')
      .attr('cx', () => 0.3 * width)
      .attr('cy', () => 0.1 * height);
  };
}

function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function () {
    var text = d3.select(this),
      words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
      word,
      line = [],
      lineNumber = 0,
      lineHeight = 1.4, // ems
      x = text.attr('x'),
      y = text.attr('y'),
      dy = parseFloat(text.attr('dy')),
      tspan = text
        .text(null)
        .append('tspan')
        .attr('x', x)
        .attr('y', y)
        .attr('dy', dy + 'em');

    while ((word = words.pop())) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(' '));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(' '));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text
          .append('tspan')
          .attr('x', x)
          .attr('y', y)
          .attr('dy', ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + 'em')
          .text(word);
      }
    }
  });
} //wrap ```
````